# using javascript to do all div sizing to overcome browser support for vh, vm, and css calc

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fluid-layout, viewport-units

Goal:  Site that fits any screen size and orientation fluidly without scroll.  I've got the ridiculous math problem packing part worked out with a different layouts per media query, in SassMeister:

http://sassmeister.com/gist/8f9954aa8973b97f43c8

Only way I could do it is with calc based on vh and vw for the sizing of all divs.  Both calc and viewport units are an issue for safari 5, Opera mini, IE8.

Without access to vh, vw, calc, any polyfill would be failing to fit screen exactly without scroll.

So... I'm new to this, and don't throw tomatoes, but is it possible (and not insane) to use javascript to:

1) retrieve the vh and vw values upon load and resize (this part I know can be done with viewport, verge, etc)

2) replace all the css calc functions with the same inside javascript

3) output the resulting div sizes to the stylesheet

Help greatly appreciated, but I realize this would mean javascript is responsible for the entire layout and that's frowned upon. I just can't see how else to do it.  If there's a solid practical reason the concept is doomed, or another approach, I'd like to know about that too.

Thank you.

Comment: What happened to old fashion media queries?

Comment: Your “goal” is more or less your main problem here IMHO. Get used to the idea, that a website does not look the same on all possible screen sizes – and it does not have to. “Insisting” on having the layout in your example even on really small screens would be rather stupid. The user does not benefit from you trying to force your fixed layout onto their tiny screen no matter what. Your time would be better invested in trying to find a different layout for smaller screens, that _does_ work, and does not need ridiculous measures like calculating all measurements via JS.

Comment: Take for instance your logo in the example, that does seem to take up between about 1/4 and 1/3 of the total screen width – why would you _insist_ on having that be the case even on the smallest screen? As a user of a small screen device, I could not care less about it – it is just _stealing_ valuable real estate here, that could be used to present actual _content_ that I am interested in …

Comment: I agree.  This was more a proof of concept markup.  I've actually ditched the logo entirely in the dev version I'm working on as it's baked into other images.  I'm not trying to make it the same on all screens.  On smaller screens, there should be barely any elements there...  My concept has always been mobile first.  I'm just trying to do it without the scrolling so the body fits the screen... then what SHOULD be on that screen is determined by the size and aspect ratio.

Comment: @slime, media queries aren't the issue.  Mockup uses them.  Lack of browser support for viewport units and calc is.  It's not getting the numbers... it's being able to use them.

Comment: Calc actually has good support and you seem to be wanting to use vh and vw for the sake of using them? They are a nice bonus, but not necessary at all to hit every screen size. %, px, and media queries is more than enough to accomplish what you want.

Comment: I know I'm not the only one because I can see javascript out there like verge, vminpoly, etc to get viewport dimensions and fix unit support, and I see people trying various techniques to insert js data back into stylesheet.  Goal always seems same as mine too... to make it MORE customized, so site is always optimized for that size screen in that orientation without relying on a generic overflow, but custom tailored to fit exactly every time.  Only part I haven't seen is people using js calc to overcome css calc support.  Wondering if there is a practical reason to avoid div sizing this way.

Comment: I have open ears.  I'm learning.  I don't care about IE8, but caniuse shows 82%.  No support for opera which is big in asia, etc which I do care about.  Broke in my own install of safari 5.  Am I putting too much stock in that?  Maybe.  Viral video sharing site.  If doable with no overflow without vp units, I'm all ears, but the only other way I can see to do it is flexbox.  I don't see it with % if some divs have to have fixed ratios (16x9 video.)  The height can't both be a percentage of the outer div AND be fixed relative to the width.  It's actually quite a bit of math to pack it fluidly.

Comment: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/

Answer (score 0):

I can answer that part about the javascript replacing vw and vh. in my code they didnt work so I had to come up with and alternative. here it is:

first, I set an onload function for the body tag.

```
<body onload="screenSize()">
```

then I had the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function screenSize(){var screenSize=screen.width;
    document.body.style.fontSize=screenSize+"px"}
</script>
```

what this does, is that it sets the base font to the amount of pixels in the width of the screen. when you declare a font size, you can use the % measurement rather than vw. the reason you can do this is because you set the size to the entire screen, so 1% means that the font-size is 1 percent of the screen, or 1vw. I'm not sure if this works instead of vh as well, but this made my code responsive to different screens and I did not use a single media query. hope this helps.

**EDIT:** I'm sorry,I misread. in order to get the vw value, you would use the previous script and then add this script:

```
var screenSize = screen.width;
var elemSize=window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("yourElement"))
var elemSize=parseInt(elemSize.fontSize)
var vwValue= (elemSize*100)/screenSize
```

the variable vwValue is the size of vw on the element. I'm sure that if you're adjusting, you can just set the script as

```
yourElement.style.fontSize=yourVwAmount+"vw"
```